# Trying to include iPhone OpenGLES headers in C++ code

Tags: c++, iphone, opengl-es

I have some C++ doing OpenGL drawing and am trying to figure out how to include the opengl headers without it giving me thousands of errors in the obj-c code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not getting any errors.
Are you doing

`#include <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>`

?

Answer (score 2):

You can save your files as .mm instead of .cpp. 
You will still be able to use C++ functions within it, but you will also be able to #import the various include files you need, as well as mix C++ and Obj-C in code.